# Update all records with slightly different data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 50,000+ records in `Post` table. I want to update `time` of all records and it should be like the time of first post is current time and second post is current time - 2 hours and so on..

The manual query for each row will be:

```
update Post set time = dateadd(hour, -2, sysdatetime()) where id = 1
update Post set time = dateadd(hour, -4, sysdatetime()) where id = 2
update Post set time = dateadd(hour, -6, sysdatetime()) where id = 3
```

I can't do above for all records, this there a way to achieve this in single query like:

```
declare @time int
set @time =  -2
update Post set time = dateadd(hour, @time + @time, sysdatetime())
```

Comment: How do you define "first post"?  Why does one block of code refer to `Post` and the other to `Ad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE and window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select p.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from post p
     )
update toupdate
    set time = dateadd(hour, -2 * seqnum, sysdatetime()) ;
```